# Display Specific conditional hash from yaml using ruby

Tags: ruby, yaml

I am trying to display a specific hash/array from yaml file using ruby
My yaml file is below

```
offices:
  location: xyz
  employees:
    jack:
      id: jack_001
      role: developer
      address: uk
      primary_contact: xyz@gmail.com
    tom: 
      id: tom_001
      role: tester
      address: usa
      primary_contact: abc@gmail.com
```

Now from the above I would like to display with condition with ruby

for example if employee_name == jack then provide me primary_contact and role values

I am trying the below code

```
require 'yaml'
yaml = YAML::load(File.open("/etc/puppetlabs/facter/facts.d/details.yaml"))
yaml_employee = yaml['offices']['employees']
puts yaml_employee
yaml_employee.each do |key, value|
if yaml_employee[key] == "jack"
 puts yaml_employee[key]['role']
 puts yaml_employee[key]['primary_contact']
```

its not printing the expected values as below

if I use the above code the expected output should print the name of the employee which is jack, role which is developer and primary contact which is xyz@gmail.com

expected output
jack, developer, xyz@gmail.com

Now from the above I would like to display with condition with ruby

for example if employee_name == jack then provide me primary_contact and role values

I am trying the below code

```
require 'yaml'
yaml = YAML::load(File.open("/etc/puppetlabs/facter/facts.d/details.yaml"))
yaml_employee = yaml['offices']['employees']
puts yaml_employee
yaml_employee.each do |key, value|
if yaml_employee[key] == "jack"
 puts yaml_employee[key]['role']
 puts yaml_employee[key]['primary_contact']
```

its not printing the expected values as below

if I use the above code the expected output should print the name of the employee which is jack, role which is developer and primary contact which is xyz@gmail.com

expected output
jack, developer, xyz@gmail.com

I also want to print each block under employees name c
e.g jack and tom, but in the situation where employees names are unknown values.

Comment: `yaml_employee[key] == "jack"` will never be true. `key` in this case is either `"jack"` or `"tom"` so  `yaml_employee[key]` will be the nested `Hash` (which is already passed as value anyway). Knowing this you could change this `yaml_employee[key] == "jack"` to just `key == "jack"` and it should work. Additionally, you could change the multiple puts statements to `puts key, *value.values_at('role','primary_contact')` however this will result in printing each value on a new line so maybe you wanted `puts [key,*value.values_at('role','primary_contact')].join(',')` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Don't need each loop for retrieve data from hash, just need proper keys to get data from hash

Please try below code

```
require 'yaml'

yaml_str = <<~YAML_STR
---
offices:
  location: xyz
  employees:
    jack:
      id: jack_001
      role: developer
      address: uk
      primary_contact: xyz@gmail.com
    tom: 
      id: tom_001
      role: tester
      address: usa
      primary_contact: abc@gmail.com
YAML_STR

yaml = YAML::load(yaml_str)
      
yaml_employee = yaml['offices']['employees']
puts "Employee Data"
puts yaml_employee

puts "jack Info"

puts emp_name = "jack"
emp_info = yaml_employee[emp_name]
puts emp_info['role']
puts emp_info['primary_contact']
```

output

Employee Data

```
{"jack"=>{"id"=>"jack_001", "role"=>"developer", "address"=>"uk", "primary_contact"=>"xyz@gmail.com"}, "tom"=>{"id"=>"tom_001", "role"=>"tester", "address"=>"usa", "primary_contact"=>"abc@gmail.com"}}
jack Info
jack
developer
xyz@gmail.com
```